# Selected and unselected from HStack logic

Tags: swift, swiftui

i want that when i pressed on 5th box then all left box will fill , and when i click on eg. 1 then unselected last 4 box , but not 1,
if i clicked on 2nd box then last 3 will be unselected , Thank you in Advanced

```
 @State var SelectedAppsname  = [1,2]

                    ForEach (1..<6){ index in
                   
                    Button(action: {
                        let count = selectedAppsName.count
                        print(count, "count")
                        print(index,"index")
                        
                        if selectedAppsName.contains(index) {
                            print(index, "inINdex")
                            for i in 0..<count {
                                if (index<=i) {
                              
                                }
                                else {
                                    let new = count - index
                                    print(new, "new")
                                selectedAppsName.removeLast(new)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            for i in count + 1...index {
                            selectedAppsName.append(i)
                        }
                        }
                       
                    }, label: {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill(Color.secondary.opacity(0.5))
                            .frame(width: 49.4, height: 56, alignment: .center)
                    })
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill( selectedAppsName.contains(index) ? Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.9, blue: 0.02) : Color.clear))
                    
                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple:

```
    @State private var level = 0
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        level = index
                    }
                } label: {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .foregroundColor(index > level ? .gray : .yellow)
                        .frame(width: 49.4, height: 56, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```